# Load VMWare fusion at OSX startup for all users

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

Is it possible to auto load VMWare fusion at MacOS startup so that it is already running for any user that logs in to the mac?

Answer (score 1):

You can add apps to a global Login Items list by adding it to **/Library/Preferences/loginwindow.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>AutoLaunchedApplicationDictionary</key>
  <array>
    <dict>
      <key>Hide</key>
      <false/>
      <key>Path</key>
      <string>/Applications/TextEdit.app</string>
    </dict>
  </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

<sup>Replace `TextEdit.app` with the app that you want to launch.</sup>